# Codeigniter routing with variable not working

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I want to route controllername/variable to controllername/methodename/variable

routes.php

```
$route['controllername']="controllername/methodename";
```

but it does not work !

How to route with variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$route['controllername/(:num)'] = 'controllername/methodename/$1';
```

Check this also : https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: (:num) not worked my variable contain characters. I used (:any) then it work. But other metherds in that controller not worked

Answer (score 0):

try like it

```
$route['controllername/:num'] = 'controllername/methodename';
```